# How to run a function on each row of pandas dataframe in parallel

Tags: python, pandas, multiprocessing

I have a function x:

```
def xfunc (var_y, df_row):
    l=do_something(df_row[1])
    m=do_something(df_row[3])
    #write(l,m) to var_y
```

I would like to pass a row to xfunc for each row in a df and execute this in parallel.

I tried :

```
# Parallelizing using Pool.apply()
import multiprocessing as mp

# Step 1: Init multiprocessing.Pool()
pool = mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count())

out='test'
# Step 2: run `pool.apply`
[pool.apply(concord_task, args=(out,r)) for i,r in df.iterrows()]

# Step 3: close
pool.close()
```

Thanks,

Comment: have you tried solving this using broadcasting internal to `pandas`?

Comment: maybe you could look into using [dask](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe.html)

Comment: `iterrows` in `pandas` is **really** slow if, `pool.apply` won't actually help you run anything in parallel (it just runs it in another process), also it's much easier returning results rather than assigning them to something that will get lost in another process